# Write back error to datatable bulkcopy C#

Tags: c#, import-from-excel, excel-import

I want to make import data from .xlsx to database
the flow as:

xlsx->datatable->database

I copy data from excel to temp table and insert, update to official table later
Everything above work OK but **now i'm stucking at writing back error if have(data already had, constraint...)  to specific field of corresponding row in datatable and view to DataGrid**

If you went through this problems, please advise me the best way to do it
Thank you with highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this library https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/ to read .xlsx and load in DataSet / DataTable. Then run the validations in your datatable.

Its better to have a seperate datatable which you will be binding to DataGrid.

Comment: kindly mark the answer as correct, if it solves your requirement.